why code in component function be executed again after useEffect? So with the code in useEffect after a update in useLayout
I have the following code that doesn't quite fit my expectations. So I would like to ask why.

why the code in the component function would be executed again after useEffect?

why after the update in useLayout, UseEffect still executed?
import { useEffect, useState, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
console.log("count in code: ", count);
useEffect(() => {
console.log("useEffect");
}, [count]);
useLayoutEffect(() => {
console.log("count in uselayout: ", count);
setCount(1);
}, [count]);
return <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count};
}


I don't understand why the logging message  "count in code:  1"appears 3 times here.
My understanding:
From the First unseen render: I would see a "count in code:  0"
Then, logging from useLayoutEffect , then logging from useEffect.
Then the update in useLayoutEffect triggers re-rendering;
Then again: logging in count in code: 1, logging in useLayoutEffect, then logging in useeffect.
Below are logging
count in code:  0
index.js:8 count in uselayout:  0 ()
index.js:8 useEffect (there is a update in useLayoutEffect, why does this useEffect still could be excuted? Shouldnt it be skipped because of the update in useLayout )
index.js:8 count in code:  1
index.js:8 count in uselayout:  1
index.js:8 useEffect
index.js:8 count in code:  1 ( why this extra logging)


Because your App is wrapped in <StrictMode />. useEffect() will always be invoked on first render. The second invocation is because of <StrictMode />.

but you didnt answer my two questions....why count in code: appear 3 times, as I supposed there are only 2 times

and why after count in uselayout:  0 , the logging is not  count in code:  1 but useEffect  ;
